# Negating whitespace regex in character class

Tags: regex, sed

What's the best way to capture all content in a line up to the whitespace. For example, from this:

```
>Peak_7847       Chr1    23988535_23998535
```

I would like to capture

```
Peak_7847
```

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/^>\([^\s]\+\)\s.*$/\1/'
```

(which doesn't work, and captures the whole line after the `>`). If I replace `\s` with
" \t", it works:

```
sed -e 's/^>\([^ \t]\+\)\s.*$/\1/'
Peak_7847
```

How can I negate the `\s` operator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
str='>Peak_7847       Chr1    23988535_23998535'
sed 's/^>\([^[:space:]]*\).*$/\1/' <<< "$str"
Peak_7847
```

Comment: Aha, thank you! Out of curiosity, do you know why `\s` doesn't work? (I'll accept your answer when SO allows me to.)

Comment: Actually `\s` isn't supported in sed's regex engine (BRE).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+).*/\1/' file
```

But why not:

```
sed 's/\s.*//' file
```